# Not connect to db on linux server

Tags: php, mysql

I have a connection string:

```
<?php
    $conn = mysql_connect(localhost,root,abc@2014) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db(db1)or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query("SET charactor_set_results=utf8",$conn);
    mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
?>
```

My database on linux server and when i connect to server. Error show:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '@' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/folder1/config/connect.php on line 2
>   Why?

Comment: because you need to set parameters as a string("localhost","root","abc@2014")

Comment: And also have a typo within **charactor_set_results** it should be **character_set_results**

Comment: Please don't use deprecated mysql_* API and use mysqli_* or PDO instead.

Answer (score 1):

`$conn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","abc@2014") or die(mysql_error());`